# How do I find the sku on the first order for a customer?

Tags: mysql, sql

Help!

How do I find the first sku on the first order for a customer?  Assume I have a table with the following columns and am using MySQL:

- order_number
- email
- sku

For example, I know we can do the following to find the first order number:

```sql
select   email, min(order_number) 
from     orders
group by email
```

If I run the following query, it returns a seemingly random sku from the customers order history:

```sql
select   email, min(order_number), sku 
from     orders
group by email
```

I tried running a subquery, but no luck there either:

```sql
select   email, min(order_number), 
             (select sku from orders o2 
              where o2.email = o1.email 
              and o2.order_number = o1.order_number)
from     orders o1
group by email
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to adapt either duplicate to your needs quite readily. If not, please ask another question explaining the issues you are having doing so.

Comment: select sku, email,order_number from (
select sku,  email,order_number, rank() OVER( partition by email order by order_number) rn 
from     orders )rs
where rs.rn=1